# Visually/graphically representing Graph data structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

Suppose I have a graph -

```
graph = { "a" : ["c"],
          "b" : ["c", "e"],
          "c" : ["a", "b", "d", "e"],
          "d" : ["c"],
          "e" : ["c", "b"],
          "f" : []
        }
```

How can I create a visual graph as an output like the one shown below [image]

Comment: There's not one right way to do this, but I've used Graphviz in the past: https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [graphviz](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html).

(padding)

Comment: Can I also add cost of edges with that ?

Comment: @knee it's shown in the third example in that page.